# How do I execute an exe on kubuntu?

Tags: linux

I have never used kubuntu so sorry for this stupid question. I have downloaded Linux x86 Libc6 (for debian but since kubuntu as far as i know is derived from debian) from here

http://www.rebol.com/download-view.html

I decompressed in a tmp dir but double-clicking on it doesn't do anything like launching on windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to install software on a Linux system is to use a package manager. The packaging system is supposed to take care of things like installing any required libraries, adding menu entries and so on.

The Rebol folks don't provide a proper package though, just an archive containing an executable. What you did, to extract in a temporary directory and click on the executable should have worked. But since what you have is a bare executable compiled for an unspecified Linux distribution, rather than a package for your distribution, you're left with the task of making the executable work in your environment.

One thing that comes to mind is that you're missing a library. Open a text terminal and run these commands (replace `/tmp` by the path to the directory where you unpacked the `rebol` executable):

```
cd /tmp
ldd ./rebol
```

This should reports lines like `libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6`. If one of the lines reads `not found`, you're missing this particular library. Note that if you have a 64-bit system, you'll need to have the 32-bit libraries installed (at least the `ia32-libs`) since you have a 32-bit executable.

If you have all the libraries, try starting `rebol` from the terminal by typing

```
./rebol
```

This may display error messages. If you need help troubleshooting these errors, you can ask again on SU; be sure to copy-paste the whole sequence of error messages.

Comment: yes I hev 64 bits oh my that sounds complicated I'm so used to windows :) ok will try !

Answer (score 1):

Let'be more explicite about this.
To install REBOL on a 64bit, Debian based Linux distro, like Ubuntu distros, you need this:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

It installs tens of megabytes of "crap" which kind of makes the cool 1M size of REBOL irrelevant, but it will change one day. Right, Carl? ... ;)